# Express Route not being called

Tags: javascript, express

Not sure why the following routes: **'/api/auth'**, **'/api/auth/sudo'** are not working when I hit the endpoint on my browser **localhost:5003/api/auth** or **/api/auth/sudo**

/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(helmet())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build')))

require('./routes/authentication.js')(app)
require('./routes/product.js')(app)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html')) 
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5003

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT} `)
})
```

/routes/authentication.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {


  app.get('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log('THIS ROUTE IS BEING HIT')
  })


  app.get('/api/auth/sudo', (req, res) => {
      console.log('COOKIE IS SET')

  })

  app.get('/api/test', (req,res) => {
      console.log("TESTING THIS ROUTE TO SEE IF WORKS")
  })

 }
```

Only the /api/test route works.

when the routes are moved to index.js then they all work.

Comment: And what do you experience when calling the other routes? What does the browser say and what appears in the console?

Comment: Nothing on the browser since I'm not sending a response. I'm looking for the console.log on the terminal.

Comment: u sure when you hit /api/test it returns console log string u did ? did you leave /api/test route in index.js anywhere ?

Comment: possibly one of the other plugins are catching the request earlier. Can you try it without helmet? Also can you check if you have a static resource directory of api/auth ?